# What is a "synodic frame"? Can one be defined for an elliptical orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, lagrangian-points, mathematics

A description of a "synodic frame" was one of the main ingredients in [this excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21570/12102) to a question about an animation of a funky-looking orbit that several different and distinctly interesting aspects to it.

As part of the background for [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16644/12102) I plotted historical orbit data for SOHO in a rotating frame centered on a point in space *that is associated with* the Sun-Earth L1 libration point. I say associated with because in real-world orbits, and not just circular-restricted ones, L1 is more of a "[Gestalt](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21291/12102)" (or "area") than a specific, mathematically well-defined point.

If you look at the lengths to which I had to go to explain the frame of this plot, you can see that I could have used a better term, if one exists.

So here I'd like to ask both *What is a "synodic frame"?* so we could have a great answer and useful definition to link back to in the future. But I'd like to also ask *Can one be defined for an elliptical orbit?*

---

Here's the plot from the [question where the math is described](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16644/12102). It is the orbit of SOHO shown in a home-grown coordinate system. Note that the "Gestalt", faux-L1, or "instantaneous-L1" red point on the left is fixed in this frame, and the position of the Earth as a function of time, the *blue elongated sausage* on the right, *defines only the axis*.

[image]

Comment: A comment, since I know just enough on this subject to be dangerous (and dangerously wrong). Yes, it's possible. Properly defining a synodic frame in the case of elliptical orbits a key aspect of the elliptical restricted three body problem, or [ER3BP](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=ER3BP&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for short. There are various approaches. One is to scale distance and time non-linearly so as to make the orbit circular. This results in rather peculiar fictitious forces that can be treated as perturbations in the case of small eccentricity.

Comment: @DavidHammen this is an interesting comment. When reading published literature last year, I chose not to download any of the ER3BP papers I came across for no rational reason except that I thought I should "skip that" for now out of concern I'd get confused. Now perhaps it's time to give those a second look. I hadn't thought about it, but now it's obvious, that's exactly what I should read. The primary question here is still "What is a “synodic frame”?" If you or anyone are interested in simply answering that and mentioning existence of ER3BP, that would certainly be a sufficient answer here.