# Design of return trajectory from lunar polar orbit to Earth's atmosphere

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit-selection, patched-conic

Given a flight path angle, altitude and velocity at re-entry into the Earth's atmosphere, how do I go about designing the return trajectory from a polar orbit at 17km altitude about the lunar surface to intercept with the Earth at the aforementioned requirements ?

'Fundamentals of astrodynamics' discourages using patch conics... Is there any other way ?

Comment: related: [how to best patch my conics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21850/195)

Comment: According to [this paper](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/volume/missiondesign/KoLoMaRo_DMissionBook_2011-04-25.pdf) patched conics were used for the Voyager and Galileo missions as a starting point for numerical simulation. That is: solve your trajectory using patched conics, take that solution into a full N-body simulation, and make small corrections to it until it's acceptable for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Fundamentals of astrodynamics' discourages using patch conics...

While I would also discourage you from *relying* on patched conics I would certainly encourage you to *try using* patched conics as a very useful, educational exercise!

Patched conics is a methodology based on Keplerian orbits. Remember that in this case the Earth and Moon move in elliptical Keplerian orbits *around a common center of mass which is almost 5000 kilometers away from the center of the Earth!*

If you feel you can neglect the rotation of the Earth-Moon system around the Sun for a few days, then you can certainly try this method as a first approximation, but *choose your conics carefully* and make sure that when you patch between an Moon orbit and an Earth orbit that you get the relative motion correct.

> Is there any other way?

Yes there certainly are!

A strategy I would suggest would be to use some patched conic solver to generate an initial orbit and the impulsive maneuver, then try to port that to a numerical simulation in the Earth-Moon system.

It's not easy, it take some 3D thinking and math to translate it to the Earth-Moon system, but you can then see how far off the patched conics solution is in the real word. Then by fine-tuning the initial orbit and the impulsive burn you can converge on a real numerical solution.

Once that works, you can add the motion of the Earth-Moon system around the sun and see once again how far off you are, and tweak further to recover your atmospheric reentry.